# my tableView cell won't display my image. I am trying to create an app where user selects photos from the photolibrary and show images in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here's my code.  I suspect the cellForRowAt() method is the culprit here. I have a Person class, that looks like this.  I create an instance of that in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo() method, and then I append it to the imageArray.  I think the table Cell doesn't have an imageView, is that right?  even thought what exactly am I displaying inside the cellForRowAt() method where i try to show both the image and the image name?

I added some print statements, and when app runs, imageArray.count is zero.  Is that because the cellForRowAt() method isn't working properly? I am not getting any errors.   My tableView is embeded inside navigationController and my cell identifier is correct.

Please help!

```
import UIKit

class Person: NSObject, Codable {
    var names: String
    var photos: String

    
    init(names: String, photos: String) {
        self.names = names
        self.photos = photos

    }
}
```

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  milestone3


import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var imagesArray = [Person]()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addPeople))
        print(imagesArray.count)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Detail", for: indexPath)
        let Person = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(Person.photos)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath.path)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Person.names
        return cell
    }

    @objc func addPeople(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else{return}
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        if let jpegdata = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8){
            try? jpegdata.write(to: imagePath)
        }
        let person = Person(names: "Unknown", photos: imageName)
        
        imagesArray.append(person)
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        print(imagesArray.count)
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Hello")
    }
    
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL{
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }

}
```

Comment: When you run your app initially and you haven't selected any images yet then of course `imagesArray` is empty. Since you never save the data, each time you restart the app `imagesArray` starts out empty. You may be saving the images but you are not saving the names or attempting to load the previously saved images. But that's a completely separate issue of an image not appearing in a cell after you  select an image. Use the debugger and see what happens exactly as you run your code.

Comment: Do you mean using something like Json and Codable to save the images into the documents directory then reload it back?

Comment: The images themselves are being saved. But you make no attempt to save (or load) the array of `Person`. Encoding that array as JSON is one option.

Comment: I thought the images should still show in the tableView cell because isn't that what the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo() method is doing or do I have it totally wrong?

Comment: That's what it should be doing, yes. But you need to verify what it's actually doing using the debugger.